# Make Page Viewer Display Different Content for Each Workspace Instance

Tags: meeting-workspace, page-viewer-web-part

When I schedule meetings and link them to the same workspace, the Web Parts are the same across each instance and the Shared Documents Libraries in each instance differ in content. However, once I set the link to display in Page Viewer in one instance, it shows that content in every instance.

How can I set things up so that I can display a different link in Page Viewer for each instance in the workspace?